# Why is this global counter not decrementing in the child process?

Tags: c, process, fork, parent-child

In this snippet, (ignoring all the `printf`s besides second last), I expect the `counter` to be at 1 by the end.

```
int counter = 1; //GLOBAL!

int main() 
{
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("child has spoken!\n");
        counter--; 
        printf("and counter is now: %d\n", counter);    
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        printf("what is counter here?: %d\n", counter);
        printf("now we'll wait\n");
        wait(NULL);
        printf("we've waited long enough!\n");
        printf("counter = %d\n", ++counter);
        printf("counter is 2????: %d\n", counter);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

The process can be seen in what is printed to output.

```
what is counter here?: 1
now we'll wait
child has spoken!
and counter is now: 0
we've waited long enough!
counter = 2
counter is 2????: 2
```

The `else` is entered first, `counter` is still at 1, we `wait(NULL)` for the `child` to die. Back up in the `if`, `fork()` creates the child, but seeing as `fork() == 0`, only the `child` decrements the `counter` by 1. Now the `counter` is 0, and the `child` terminates at `exit(0)`. The wait is over, `child` is dead, and `parent` prints `++counter` which should be 0 + 1 = 1, but suddenly it's 2, not 1! Why is this so?

Comment: Related: [Is data shared between processes when we use fork in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901590/is-data-shared-between-processes-when-we-use-fork-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Linux man page for `fork`:

> Under  Linux,  fork() is implemented using copy-on-write pages, so the only penalty that it incurs is the time and memory required to duplicate the parent's page tables, and to create  a  unique  task  structure  for  the child.

This means that any time you write to memory in either the parent or child process, the page being written is copied and the two processes end up with independent copies.